# gatling websocket check with count not working

Tags: scala, websocket, performance-testing, gatling

I'm running a performance test on a websocket. The websocket is returning a heartbeat message every 3 seconds and several data messages. 
I want to collect the messages returned by the websockt within a specific time interval (10 seconds) and count the data messages ignoring the heartbeat messages.

If I do the following

```
.exec(ws("ws send message")
  .sendText(wsmessages.message)
    .check(wsAwait.within(10 seconds).expect(5 to 30)
      .regex("^someid").findAll.saveAs("count")
   ))
.exec(session => { println("message count: " + 
  session("count").as[Seq[String]].size); session })
```

the list size has the expected amount and is printed to the console. But if I change the call to

```
.exec(ws("ws send message")
  .sendText(wsmessages.message)
    .check(wsAwait.within(10 seconds).expect(5 to 30)
      .regex("^someid").count.greateThanOrEqual(5)
   ))
```

I'm getting a Check failed: Timeout error

Is the count not usable on the regex check?